# Swift diamond shaped UIButton with titleLabel

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'd like to create a diamond shaped UIButton in Swift with a titleLabel. My problem is, that titleLabel text shrinks and it shows only three dots. How can I extend the frame of titleLabel to get enough space for the title?

Here is my code (width and height is 70 points).

```
private let diamondButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    button.setTitle("More", for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = .red
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    button.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / 4))
    button.titleLabel?.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / -4))
    button.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
    button.titleLabel?.backgroundColor = .blue // Just for demonstration
    button.titleLabel?.bounds = button.frame
    button.titleLabel?.layer.masksToBounds = true
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
    return button
}()
```

Comment: by `button.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true` you can adjust font size inside button, and maybe `button.titleLabel?.clipsToBounds = false` and `button.minimumFontSize = 14` could solve your problem

Comment: Thank you for your response Arash. Unfortunately it didn't solve the issue. I tried with:
```
button.titleLabel?.clipsToBounds = true button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

Comment: if you set `button.titleLabel?.clipsToBounds = false` you should set `button.clipsToBounds = false` too, and for adjusting font size you don't need titleLabel

Comment: Still doesn't work. I also tried to add UILabel as a subview to the button, but that''s not an elegant solution.

Comment: Problem is that double rotation is not the right way to make a diamond shaped button.

Comment: Yes, double rotation shrinks the label...Matt, what do you suggest? I don't want to use image....

Comment: How about diamond shaped button _image_? And maybe even diamond shaped button _mask_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why rotating button? You can insert view under title label, and make it the same size and centered within the button, but being rotated.

```
private let diamondButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    button.setTitle("More", for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = .clear
    button.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)

    let diamond = UIView(frame: button.bounds)
    diamond.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    diamond.isUserInteractionEnabled = false // button will handle touches
    // Handle it gracefully without force unwrapping
    button.insertSubview(diamond, belowSubview: button.titleLabel!)
    diamond.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / 4))
    diamond.backgroundColor = .red
    diamond.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    diamond.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    diamond.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: diamond.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    diamond.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    diamond.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    return button
}()
```

You can play with constraints if you need BGR bigger than button a bit, also it looks best if button is square (but you can again fix it with constraints of inner diamond)